# linqtodb use connection.BeginTransactionAsync inside asp.net core

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, ado.net, linq2db

I'm using linqtodb with great success inside a asp.net 6.0 api.
But now i'm at a point where it looks like i need to use transactions and it looks like i'm misunderstanding a few things there.
i'm getting the _connection object as an injected object in the service

the error i get:

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action\u00601 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action\u00601 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock
...
...
"message":"Transaction (Process ID 56) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction."
```

the code in question is:

```cs
...
    await _connection.BeginTransactionAsync(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable);
                    sql = "SELECT ISNULL(MAX(CAST(Code AS INT)),0) FROM [@COR_DIA_AKM_LOTAT]";
                        var maxCode = await _connection.ExecuteAsync<int>(sql) + 1;
                        string newCode = maxCode.ToString("00000000");
                        sql = "INSERT INTO [@COR_DIA_AKM_LOTAT] (Code, Name, U_DocEntry, U_LineNum, U_LotNum, U_LotQty, U_ItemCode, U_Typ, U_DeletedF, U_LotCode) VALUES (@newCode, @newCode, @docEntry, @lineNum, @lot, @qty, @itemCode, 'F', 'N', '')";
                    await Task.Delay(10000);
                    await _connection.ExecuteAsync(sql,
                            new DataParameter { Name = "@newCode", Value = newCode },
                            new DataParameter { Name = "@qty", Value = l.qty },
                            new DataParameter { Name = "@docEntry", Value = updatePos.docEntry },
                            new DataParameter { Name = "@lineNum", Value = updatePos.lineNum },
                            new DataParameter { Name = "@itemCode", Value = updatePos.itemCode },
                            new DataParameter { Name = "@lot", Value = l.lot }
                            );
                    await _connection.CommitTransactionAsync();
...
```

so as you maybe can see there needs to be created an incremental alphanumeric id first (structure is given, i cannot change that)
and then i will use it in an insert.

So i need to make sure that concurrent usage of the above part will wait for eachother to finish

The await Task.Delay(...) is just there so i can Test the concurrent usage

When i now execute this code from 2 separate clients the second call from the 2nd client fails with the above message

things i've considered but are not applicable:

- use a stored procedure
- use one sql statement and get the new id as a result from a subquery
- use a mutex lock in the application (bad idea anyway i guess)

what i expect from the code:

- the 2nd client waits until it can get the lock. this waiting will be done automagically from within my await ...BeginTransaction() right?

Here the model of the table in question:

```cs
    [Table(Schema = "dbo", Name = "@COR_DIA_AKM_LOTAT")]
    public partial class @COR_DIA_AKM_LOTAT : IUDT
    {
        [PrimaryKey, NotNull] public string Code { get; set; }
        [Column, NotNull] public string Name { get; set; }

        [Column, NotNull] public int U_DocEntry { get; set; }

        [Column, NotNull] public int U_LineNum { get; set; }
        [Column] public decimal U_LotQty { get; set; }


        [Column] public string U_DeletedF { get; set; }
        [Column] public string U_LotNum { get; set; }

        [Column] public decimal U_PkgMandatoryQty { get; set; }
    }
```

any enlightment is highly appreciated

**Update**

My misunderstanding was that i was thinking

```cs
...BeginTransaction(..)
```

Will already lock the table somehow. But now after some more reading and pointers from @SvyatoslavDanyliv i've found out that locking is happening on query level. So to get the behaviour i want i need to:

```cs
// read committed is fine because i just would like to lock -> execute queries -> commit 
 using var trans = await _connection.BeginTransactionAsync(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
// UPDLOCK is important here because it will start the lock
sql = @"SELECT ISNULL(MAX(CAST(Code AS INT)),0) FROM [@COR_DIA_AKM_LOTAT] WITH (UPDLOCK)";
var maxCode = await _connection.ExecuteAsync<int>(sql) + 1;
string newCode = maxCode.ToString("00000000");
sql = "INSERT INTO [@COR_DIA_AKM_LOTAT] (Code, Name, U_DocEntry, U_LineNum, U_LotNum, U_LotQty, U_ItemCode, U_Typ, U_DeletedF, U_LotCode) VALUES (@newCode, @newCode, @docEntry, @lineNum, @lot, @qty, @itemCode, 'F', 'N', '')";
await Task.Delay(4000);
await _connection.ExecuteAsync(sql, ...)
...more queries
await _connection.CommitTransactionAsync();
```

Comment: `[@COR_DIA_AKM_LOTAT]` has model? Could you update question with this class?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv just updated the question. thanks for catching up on this

but hey

it's not using the model in that case anyway.

Comment: Additional question. Which database do you use?

Comment: Ms Sql Server 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `linq2db` was created to maximally avoid Raw SQL usage, there is the way how to insert such record without transaction.

```cs
// tricky part, creating LINQ query which returns result set with calculated 'newCode'
var maxQuery = db.SelectQuery<string>(() =>
        Sql.ConvertTo<string>.From(
            db.GetTable<COR_DIA_AKM_LOTAT>().Max(x => Sql.ConvertTo<int?>.From(x.Code)) ?? 0 + 1)
    )
    .AsSubQuery()  // introducing subquery to help better PadLeft calculation
    .Select(x => Sql.PadLeft(x, 8, '0'))
    .AsSubQuery(); // additional subquery because value will be used twice

// inserting prepared value into destination table
maxQuery.Insert(db.GetTable<COR_DIA_AKM_LOTAT>(),
    newCode =>
        new COR_DIA_AKM_LOTAT
        {
            Code = newCode, 
            Name = newCode,
            U_DocEntry = updatePos.docEntry,
            U_LineNum = updatePos.lineNum,
            U_LotNum = l.lot,
            U_LotQty = l.qty,
            U_ItemCode = updatePos.itemCode,
            U_Typ = "F",
            U_DeletedF = "N",
            U_LotCode = ""
        });
```

Query should generate the following SQL (some values changed for successful test execution):

```cs
INSERT INTO [dbo].[@COR_DIA_AKM_LOTAT]
(
    [Code],
    [Name],
    [U_DocEntry],
    [U_LineNum],
    [U_LotNum],
    [U_LotQty],
    [U_DeletedF],
    [U_PkgMandatoryQty]
)
SELECT
    [t1].[c1],
    [t1].[c1],
    1,
    1,
    N'1',
    1,
    N'N',
    1
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            IIF(Len([x_1].[c1]) > 8, [x_1].[c1], Replicate(N'0', 8 - Len([x_1].[c1])) + [x_1].[c1]) as [c1]
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    Convert(NVarChar(11), Coalesce((
                        SELECT
                            Max(Convert(Int, [x].[Code]))
                        FROM
                            [dbo].[@COR_DIA_AKM_LOTAT] [x]
                    ), 1)) as [c1]
            ) [x_1]
    ) [t1]
```

Anyway better to think about special table which contains last increment value. Because calculating Max by string field is not good option for performance.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. Something like this could work indeed. Its cool to see that we can construct queries like that using linq2db.
How about if i need the freshly created newCode as well in some queries that get executed later in the path?
Anyway you have mentioned that keeping the latest number in a sep. table for performance reason could be a  good idea. That exactly imo would raise the same question here again using the .BeginTransaction(...) - approach.
But if it's not possible at all this shall be the accepted answer.

Comment: Problem here with Serialized transaction - it is escalated to deadlock. You can generate new ID's without transaction. Minus here that you can have gaps between IDs if transaction failed.

Comment: So i'll try to rephrase my question: how can we execute multiple queries on a connection (using .net) and make sure they are all executed as an atomic operation?
It looks like i'm missing some basic know how here.

Comment: Well, BeginTransaction is proper function. But Serialized transaction is too strict and usually may cause deadlocks. Actually you block whole table `@COR_DIA_AKM_LOTAT`. For further reading [TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Ok, good to know. But i don't get why i should not use serialized transaction isolation level. Because i want to lock the table for the duration of the executed SELECT and the following INSERT statement so no other Process/Thread can Read or Write to this table for this short duration. So i'm a bit puzzled why i'm getting a "deadlock" here. Will need to elaborate further.
Thank you very much for your code and pointers. It's highly appreciated

Comment: fyi: After elaborating i've found a solution which works properly when using ...BeginTransaction(...).
See the Update - Section in the question

Comment: I think better to use `using` keyword for started transaction.